# Verb similar to patron of establishment

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to say: "We end up really liking the bourgeoisie establishments we **visit**."

But visit seems like a weak word for the job. In my mind, I want a verb which has the connotation of refinement and taste similar to the noun "patron". Does such a word or phrase exist?

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit clearer about what you're asking.  "Bourgeoisie" means the middle class.  The adjectival form is "bourgeoise," and it carries the connotation of stuffy conventionality, which seems at odds with "refinement and taste."  In English a patron is either a benefactor or a regular customer, and it seems likely that the latter is what you're thinking.  But again, patrons in that sense aren't necessarily refined and tasteful.  Unfortunately, in France, the *patron* is the owner of a restaurant, but I can't tell if that's what you mean either.

Comment: I believe the word you are seeking is *patronise*. We end up really liking the bourgeois establishments we *patronise*.

Comment: @deadrat The adjective in English, surely, is *bourgeois*. In French one would add the e if the noun it qualifies is feminine e.g. *une femme bourgeoise*, but *un home bourgeois*. And it is the masculine form which applies in English.

Comment: @WS2 You are surely correct.  Thank you.

Comment: @deadrat Thank you for explaining the need for clarification. The word I intend to use is in fact _bougie_ which informally refers to anything (esp. consumption) that's perceived as upscale or extravagant. I wasn't sure how slang would be received on this Stack Exchange. With respect to the expansion of bougie I selected, I revisited the dictionary and realized the difference between bourgeois (an individual) vs. bourgeoisie (the middle class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a somewhat witty word would work then I suggest

**haunt**

as a verb (manifest itself at [a place] regularly)
but also as a nod to the noun (a place frequented by a specified person).

(Definitions from Google)

> We end up really liking the bougie establishments we haunt.

Answer (score 2):

Like **deadrat** & **WS2**, I would first recommend (for its continental *flavor*) [“**patronize**.”](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=hss&oq=patronize&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=patronize+definition&gs_l=hp..1.0l5.0.0.3.99800...........0.enfVCUYWi3A&gws_rd=ssl) Next, I'd go with "**frequent**," e.g., "We ended up really liking the bourgeoisie establishments we “*frequented*.”

> [**frequent**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=frequent+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=frequent+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.1.1693357...........0.OpjFtFMUDEk&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: **1**. visit (a place) often or habitually. "bars ***frequented*** by soldiers"
>
> **synonyms**: visit, patronize, spend time in, visit regularly, be a regular visitor to, haunt; *informal* hang out at; see, Google